# How to suppress text from binom.test in R output

Tags: r

I wanted to determine the CI for a binomial test:

```
b <- binom.test(73,85)
bUpper <- b$conf.int[2]-b$estimate[1]
bUpper
```

probability of success 
            0.06604512

How do i get rid of the line that says 'probability of success' ? Now that i have subtracted the estimate from the upper conference interval limit, this should no longer apply

Thanks
Chris

Comment: you can access it directly with `bUpper[[1]]`

Comment: Thanks, that is great!

Comment: or even this `bUpper["probability of success"][[1]]`

Answer (score 2):

You can do that:

```
bUpper[[1]]
[1] 0.06604512
```

Or analogously to Maurits solution:

```
b$conf.int[2]-b$estimate[[1]]
[1] 0.06604512
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this.

```
as.numeric(bUpper)
[1] 0.06604512
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `unname`

```
bUpper <- b$conf.int[2] - unname(b$estimate[1])
bUpper
#[1] 0.06604512
```